# Controlling alignment between equations when journal does not like array

Tags: align, arrays

I just got a report back on a paper I submitted to a journal, and one of the things the editor wants me to do is to replace all instances of `array` with `align`. The paper as submitted contained the following:

```
\[ \begin{array}{l@{}l@{}lcc@{}c@{}ccr@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r}
\sigma^{\ast}(x^3) &+& \tau^{\ast}(x^3) &=& (x+y)^3 &+& x^3 &=& 2 x^3 &+& 3 x^2 y &+& 3 x y^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{\ast}(x^2 y) &+& \tau^{\ast}(x^2 y) &=& (x+y)^2 y &+& x^2 (x+y) &=& x^3 &+& 2 x^2 y &+& 2 x y^2 &+& y^3  \\
\sigma^{\ast}(x y^2) &+& \tau^{\ast}(x y^2) &=& (x+y) y^2 &+& x (x+y)^2 &=&  x^3 &+& 2x^2 y &+& 2 x y^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{\ast}(y^3) &+& \tau^{\ast}(y^3) &=& y^3 &+& (x+y)^3 &=& x^3 &+& 3 x^2 y &+& 3 x y^2 &+& 2 y^3  \\
\end{array} \]
```

[image]

Trying to write this with `align`, I came up with

```
\begin{align*}
\sigma^{\ast}(x^3) &+ \tau^{\ast}(x^3) &= (x+y)^3 &+ x^3 &= 2 x^3 &+ 3 x^2 y &+ 3 x y^2 &+ y^3 \\
\sigma^{\ast}(x^2 y) &+ \tau^{\ast}(x^2 y) &= (x+y)^2 y &+ x^2 (x+y) &= x^3 &+ 2 x^2 y &+ 2 x y^2 &+ y^3  \\
\sigma^{\ast}(x y^2) &+ \tau^{\ast}(x y^2) &= (x+y) y^2 &+ x (x+y)^2 &=  x^3 &+ 2x^2 y &+ 2 x y^2 &+ y^3 \\
\sigma^{\ast}(y^3) &+ \tau^{\ast}(y^4) &= y^3 &+ (x+y)^3 &= x^3 &+ 3 x^2 y &+ 3 x y^2 &+ 2 y^3  
\end{align*}
```

[image]

In my opinion, the second is much worse. The + and = signs aren't aligned; the choice to use white space around = and not around + for easier parsing has been removed; matching monomials are no longer aligned.

After a bit more mucking around, I came up with

```
 \begin{alignat*}{14}
&\sigma^{\ast}(x^3) &&+ \tau^{\ast}(x^3) & \ \ = \ \  & (x+y)^3 &+& x^3 & \ \ = \ \  && 2 x^3 &+& 3 x^2 y &+& 3 x y^2 &+& y^3 \\
&\sigma^{\ast}(x^2 y) &&+ \tau^{\ast}(x^2 y) & \ \ = \ \  & (x+y)^2 y &+& x^2 (x+y) & \ \ = \ \  && x^3 &+& 2 x^2 y &+& 2 x y^2 &+& y^3  \\
&\sigma^{\ast}(x y^2) &&+ \tau^{\ast}(x y^2) & \ \ = \ \  & (x+y) y^2 &+& x (x+y)^2 & \ \ = \ \  &&  x^3 &+& 2x^2 y &+& 2 x y^2 &+& y^3 \\
&\sigma^{\ast}(y^3) &&+ \tau^{\ast}(y^4) & \ \ = \ \  & y^3 &+& (x+y)^3 & \ \ = \ \  && x^3 &+& 3 x^2 y &+& 3 x y^2 &+& 2 y^3  
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

This isn't terrible -- I liked the middle equation terms centered better than left-justified, but it isn't a big deal -- but this certainly seemed like abusing the `alignat` environment and the spacing around the +'s seems less consistent. Is there a more readable way to produce something like the top version without using `array`?

Comment: There are two main issues with both the `array` and the `alignat*` environments: (a) there's no whitespace around the `+` symbols and (b)there's an excessive amount of whitespace around the `=` symbols.

Comment: you can use `alignat` but lose the `\ ` around the =

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am putting the slashes there in order to make more space around the equals signs than the pluses. (The same reason I have @{} flanking the + signs but @ flanking the = signs in the array version.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer if `alignat` is used as intended (see Mico's answer) you get standard spacing for + and = so bigger space around = as it is a`\mathrel` and + is a `\mathbin`

Answer (score 3):

Quite likely the reviewer was objecting more on the uneven spacings, rather than on the specific way the display is realized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% let TeX add spaces
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% emulate align
\newcolumntype{O}{>{{}}c<{{}}}% operations and relations
\begin{array}{
  l % first column
  O % operation
  l % second column
  O % relation
  c % third column
  O % operation
  c % fourth column
  O % relation
  r % fifth column
  O % operation
  r % sixth column
}
\sigma^{*}(x^3)  &+& \tau^{*}(x^3)  &=&  (x+y)^3 &+&   x^3    &=& 2x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{*}(x^2y) &+& \tau^{*}(x^2y) &=& (x+y)^2y &+& x^2(x+y) &=&  x^3 + 2x^2y + 2xy^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{*}(xy^2) &+& \tau^{*}(xy^2) &=& (x+y)y^2 &+& x(x+y)^2 &=&  x^3 + 2x^2y + 2xy^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{*}(y^3)  &+& \tau^{*}(y^3)  &=&    y^3   &+&  (x+y)^3 &=&  x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 &+& 2y^3\\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've removed some alignment points, due to the fact that the middle terms in the final polynomials have similar structure, so they are naturally aligned, but they can be added back if need arise using the same scheme.

The `O` column type is introduced locally just to ease input. How does it work? First I set intercolumn spacing to zero, but add `{}` at either side of the operation or relation symbols, so TeX's rules of space insertion work automatically.

A very similar output can be obtained with `IEEEeqnarray`. See https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf for instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{lClCcCcCrCr}
\sigma^{*}(x^3)  &+& \tau^{*}(x^3)  &=&  (x+y)^3 &+&   x^3    &=& 2x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{*}(x^2y) &+& \tau^{*}(x^2y) &=& (x+y)^2y &+& x^2(x+y) &=&  x^3 + 2x^2y + 2xy^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{*}(xy^2) &+& \tau^{*}(xy^2) &=& (x+y)y^2 &+& x(x+y)^2 &=&  x^3 + 2x^2y + 2xy^2 &+& y^3 \\
\sigma^{*}(y^3)  &+& \tau^{*}(y^3)  &=&    y^3   &+&  (x+y)^3 &=&  x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 &+& 2y^3\\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh, I like this. We'll see if the reviewer approves.

Comment: I like the readability of the code, but this really is showing a more readable way to work with array, not a way to make align do what I way doing with array.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Centering columns is very difficult with `align` or `alignat`. You might want to consider `IEEEeqnarray`. Let me check.

Answer (score 2):

The editor is making too much of a distinction between what can be produced with `array` and `alignat*` environments. Here's a demonstration that the outputs of `array` and `alignat*` environments can, in fact, be virtually indistinguishable from one another -- as well as be typographically correct, of course.

[image]

There are four separate aspects to making the output of `array` look the same as that of `alignat*`: (a) setting `\arraycolsep` to 0pt; (b) creating a bespoke column type to "house" the `+` and `=` symbols to make sure they're treated by TeX as binary and relational operators, respectively; (c) ensuring that the other mathy parts are processed in `\displaystyle` by default; and (d) increasing the value of `\arraystretch` by about one third.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' env.
\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}  % for binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % automatic display-style math mode

\begin{document}
  
% Solution 1: An 'array' env. inside a \[ ... \] group
\[ 
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}      % default: 5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.35} % default: 1.0
\begin{array}{ *{7}{LC} L } % make full use of 'L' and 'C' column types
\sigma^*(x^3)   &+& \tau^*(x^3)   &=& (x+y)^3   &+& x^3       &=& 2 x^3 &+& 3 x^2 y &+& 3 x y^2 &+& y^3  \\
\sigma^*(x^2 y) &+& \tau^*(x^2 y) &=& (x+y)^2 y &+& x^2 (x+y) &=& x^3   &+& 2 x^2 y &+& 2 x y^2 &+& y^3  \\
\sigma^*(x y^2) &+& \tau^*(x y^2) &=& (x+y) y^2 &+& x (x+y)^2 &=& x^3   &+& 2x^2 y  &+& 2 x y^2 &+& y^3  \\
\sigma^*(y^3)   &+& \tau^*(y^3)   &=& y^3       &+& (x+y)^3   &=& x^3   &+& 3 x^2 y &+& 3 x y^2 &+& 2 y^3 
\end{array} 
\]

% Solution 2: Standalone alignat* environment
\begin{alignat*}{8} % Why 8? There are 15 '&' symbols per row, and (15+1)/2=8.
&\sigma^*(x^3)   &&+ \tau^*(x^3)   &&= (x+y)^3   &&+ x^3       &&= 2 x^3 &&+ 3 x^2 y &&+ 3 x y^2 &&+ y^3  \\
&\sigma^*(x^2 y) &&+ \tau^*(x^2 y) &&= (x+y)^2 y &&+ x^2 (x+y) &&= x^3   &&+ 2 x^2 y &&+ 2 x y^2 &&+ y^3  \\
&\sigma^*(x y^2) &&+ \tau^*(x y^2) &&= (x+y) y^2 &&+ x (x+y)^2 &&= x^3   &&+ 2x^2 y  &&+ 2 x y^2 &&+ y^3  \\
&\sigma^*(y^3)   &&+ \tau^*(y^3)   &&= y^3       &&+ (x+y)^3   &&= x^3   &&+ 3 x^2 y &&+ 3 x y^2 &&+ 2 y^3 
\end{alignat*} 
\end{document}
```